Deprecated: Optional parameter $type declared before required parameter $extra is implicitly treated as a required parameter
I'm trying to code a TG bot and when starting my bot.php in termux I get this code error and can't fix it.
if (isset($extra->prod_url)) { 
 $extra->domain = $this->getstr($extra->prod_url.'/', '://', '/'); 
 
 if (strpos($extra->prod_url, '/products/') === false) $extra->prod_url = 'https://'.$extra->domain.'/collections/all?sort=extra-sort1-ascending&sort_by=price-ascending#/sort:ss_price:asc'; 
 
 $a = $this->curlx->Get($extra->prod_url, null, $cookie, $server['proxy']); 
 
 if (!$a->success) goto start; 
 
 $extra->prod_id = empty($tmp = preg_replace('/[^\d]/', '', $this->getstr($a->body, 'variants":[{"id":', ','))) ? preg_replace('/[^\d]/', '', $this->getstr($a->body, 'variantId":', ',')) : $tmp; 
 
 if (empty($extra->prod_id)) { 
  $empty = "Product ID is Empty"; 


This is the wrong code part. It is about a function declaration parameter order. Required arguments come first, optional last. Read chapter https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php
